# Using Document Ready on Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still new to javascript.

I have an application that has two buttons on the page. One is a cpu_vs_player button that displays one game and the other is a player_vs_player button that displays a different game. The problem is that all the code is located in one application.js file. There is no need to load the player_vs_player on `$(document).ready(function(){});` if I were to play cpu_vs_player.

Any ideas on how I can get them to load only if I chose that game? (I am only using one route with all the information being hidden / shown based on the click).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document.ready is nothing more than the moment after the page has rendered and the document needs to be populated with event listeners. Frankly there are multiple way of skinning this cat.

You can either do the jQuery way where you keep javascript and HTML divided:

```
<button id="button1">cpu_vs_player</button>
<button id="button2">player_vs_player</button>
```

And for JavaScript:

Assuming you have a function for each gameplay:

```
function cpu_vs_player() {
   // start the game
}

function player_vs_player() {
   // need another player
}
```

Add event listeners the jQuery way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button1").click(function() {
      cpu_vs_player();
   });

   $("#button1").click(function() {
      player_vs_player();
   });

});
```

**OR** you could use the method @Techstone shows you, though you could do it more direct. It all works though.

```
<button onclick="javascript:cpu_vs_player();">cpu_vs_player</button>
<button onclick="javascript:player_vs_player();">player_vs_player</button>
```

---

Adding another option you can apply

In Javascript:

```
var Main = {

    cpu_vs_player: function() {
        alert("start cpu_vs_player");
    },
    player_vs_player: function() {
        alert("start player_vs_player");
    }
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<button onclick="javascript:Main.cpu_vs_player();">cpu_vs_player</button>
<button onclick="javascript:Main.player_vs_player();">player_vs_player</button>
```

And yes, there is more ...  ;-)

Comment: Ahhh awesome, thanks Daniel! I appreciate the thorough response. Helped me greatly!

Comment: I thought some more insight would be of help to your current level. The last example is based on objects. Main is an object. You may want to keep that in mind, because you will see that a lot more in your adventures in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

image that your two button and js definition like below

```
function LetsRock(Playmate) {
    ....
}

<input type='button' value='cpu_vs_player' id='cpu_vs_player' onclick='javascript:LetsRock(this.id);' />
<input type='button' value='player_vs_player' id='player_vs_player' onclick='javascript:LetsRock(this.id);' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the function with parameters (i.e. 0 to cpu v/s player, 1 to player v/s player), and send from the menu page to the `$(document).ready(function(){});`